# taking input from user in mysql c api

Tags: mysql, c, api

if we have to insert records into a mysql database using c api then the general code is this

```
    if (mysql_query(conn, "insert into empinfo values ('saikat banerjee')")) 
    {
      printf("4Error %u: %s\n", mysql_errno(conn), mysql_error(conn));
      exit(1);
    }
```

but, here we have to enter the record from the code itself .

but, i want to enter records from direct user inputs.
like, save the user input in a say, string variable and then use that string variable to store the record in the database. ie. i want to do something like this
    `char empname[100]`
and then,

```
   if (mysql_query(conn, "insert into empinfo values (empname)")) 


  {
  printf("4Error %u: %s\n", mysql_errno(conn), mysql_error(conn));
  exit(1);


   }
```

but, this is storing `NULL` in the table.

is there any way to do this?
please help!

Answer (score 0):

Mysql C (or otherwise) API don't enter into this - stdio.h does, though. I'd suggest looking the documentation for scanf and fread. Additional points for using libreadline (if on linux). Of course mysql (the CLI command) already does all this and more.

However, the second part of your question makes me think your needs are deeper, seeing that at a minimum, you'd want to do something like:

```
  sprintf(stmt, "insert into empinfo values ('%s')",empname)
  if (mysql_query(conn, stmt)) ...
```

This is about plain old C, though.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL tutorial says you do something like this:

```
char *stat = "INSERT INTO images(id, data) VALUES('1', '%s')";
len = snprintf(query, sizeof(stat)+sizeof(chunk) , stat, chunk);
```

To do it the "proper" way you should use prepared statements. See here for a tutorial: http://lgallardo.com/en/2011/06/23/sentencias-preparadas-de-mysql-en-c-ejemplo-completo/